# How to print words on a screen using a text file?

Tags: html, dart

This is my working program. I want to type my words in a text file instead of a dart [] List.

```
import 'dart:html';

List <String> words = ['testing','hurry','stop','test','work','lol'];
//How can I use a text file filled with words instead of this??

void main() {
  querySelector("#reset").onClick.listen(randomWord);
}

void randomWord(MouseEvent e) {
  words.shuffle();
  querySelector("#random_word").text = words.last.toString();
}
```

It seems its not as easy as just doing List words =('listofwords.txt'); ?  :( help

Here is a example of what I am trying to do
http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomWord

Comment: How Wil you get the text file?

Comment: Same way everyone gets images. I put the txt file in the root next to the index.html

Comment: Oya. Then why don't you put all the text into one single data.dart file? Then import it from main.dart :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're importing `dart:html`, I presume you're trying to do this from a Web app. In that case, you need an `HttpRequest` to load a file. If your text file has a list of words separated by spaces, you can do something like this:

```
import "dart:html";

List<String> words;

void main() {
  HttpRequest.getString("listofwords.txt").then((String text) {
      words = text.split(' ');
  });
}
```

Note that loading files in this manner is asynchronous, so make sure you don't try to manipulate `words` before it's been filled. You'll want to trigger such manipulation within the `then()` callback block.

Comment: I am getting a lot of undefined errors with this code. Can you be more specific so it matching the code above? 

Do I need to import something?

Comment: Ack! Sorry. I copied that code right out of the Dart docs (https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.HttpRequest#id_getString), and their example is wrong. Fixed it!

Comment: HttpRequest.getString seems to want to be defined I am not sure how to defined it so everything works?

Comment: Okay, the code listing is more complete now. Perhaps you were trying to use `HttpRequest` outside of `main()`?

Comment: yea I used it outside of main. Thanks your updated code works :)if I had my list like this
test
list
test
going up and down how would I spit it?

Comment: I mean Horizontal list

Answer (score 0):

You would wanting to be using Dart IO. I would check out the API Docs and learn a thing or two about it, as it is very useful.

https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io

Hope this helps!

Luca

Comment: I cant use import 'dart:html'; and import 'dart:io'; together so how should I go about this?